# Using Thrift for offline serialisation?

Tags: java, c#, thrift

I use Apache Thrift protocol for tablet-server and interlanguage integration, and all is OK few years.

Integration is between languages (C#/C++/PC Java/Dalvik Java) and thrift is probably one of simplest and safest. So I want pack-repack sophisticated data structures (and changed over years) with Thrift library. Lets say in thrift terms kind of OfflineTransport or OfflineProtocol.

Scenario:

I want to make backup solution, for example during internet provider failure process data in offline mode: serialise, store, try to process in few ways. For example sent serialised data by normal email via poor backup connection etc.

Question is: where in Thrift philosophy is best extension point for me?

I understand, only part of online protocol is possible to backup offline, ie real time return of value is not possible, that is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Look for serializer. There are misc. implementations but they all share the same common concept to use a buffer or file / stream as transport medium:

### Writing data in C#

E.g. we plan to store the bits into a bytes[] buffer. So one could write:

```
var trans = new TMemoryBuffer();
var prot = new TCompactProtocol( trans);
var instance = GetMeSomeDataInstanceToSerialize();
instance.Write(prot);
```

Now we can get a hold of the data:

```
var data = trans.GetBuffer();
```

### Reading data in C#

Reading works similar, except that you need to know from somewhere what root instance to construct:

```
var trans = new TMemoryBuffer( serializedBytes);
var prot = new TCompactProtocol( trans);
var instance = new MyCoolClass();
instance.Read(prot);
```

### Additional Tweaks

One solution to the chicken-egg problem during load could be to use a `union` as an extra serialization container:

```
union GenericFileDataContainer {
  1 : MyCoolClass  coolclass;
  2 : FooBar  foobar
  // more to come later
}
```

By always using this container as the root instance during serialization it is easy to add more classes w/o breaking compatibility and there is no need to know up front what exactly is in a file - you just read it and check what element is set in the union.

Answer (score 0):

There is an RPC framework that uses the standard thrift Protocol named "thrifty", and it is the same effect as using thrift IDL to define the service, that is, thrify can be compatible with code that uses thrift IDL, which is very helpful for cross-platform. And has a ThriftSerializer class in it:

```
[ThriftStruct]
public class LogEntry
{

    [ThriftConstructor]
    public LogEntry([ThriftField(1)]String category, [ThriftField(2)]String message)
    {
        this.Category = category;
        this.Message = message;
    }

    [ThriftField(1)]
    public String Category { get; }

    [ThriftField(2)]
    public String Message { get; }
}

ThriftSerializer s = new ThriftSerializer(ThriftSerializer.SerializeProtocol.Binary);
byte[] s = s.Serialize<LogEntry>();

s.Deserialize<LogEntry>(s);
```

you can try it:https://github.com/endink/Thrifty